# UV Mapped textures won't show up in Blender Game Engine

Tags: texturing, game-engine

I'm using Blender Game Engine to make a game with a city scene. I UV mapped the logos of the businesses in my city, but they don't show up when I press <kbd>P</kbd> to play the game. I've tried deleting the materials and textures but it won't work. I'm probably just not doing it right.

The blend file:

[image]

Comment: The .blend you uploaded doesn't contain any textures, so it's pretty useless. "File - External Data - Pack all into .blend". Check your file size then. blend-exchange doesn't allow uploads above 30 Megs.